# Getting XPath error trying to create a XPathQueryString

Tags: html, ios7, xpath

I am new at writing XML queries; that said, I am trying to parse some HTML.  This is the XPath query string where I am attempting to find the first occurrance:

```
    NSString *sourceXpathQueryString = @"border=0 title=\"";
```

This is what I'm looking at:

```
<div><img style="border: solid 1px #383c40; " src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51WXZRJ3B5L._SX220_.jpg' width=220  border=0 title="Women Who Run With The Wolves:  Myths And Stories Of The Wild Woman Archetype">
```

I'm getting an error:

> XPath error : Invalid expression border=0 title="

with a ^ under the first letter of title.  I have used this in regular expressions and had no problem.

I looked in Google for help, but found nothing specific to this error.  I am using an API called TFHpple to parse the HTML (which is returned correctly) in iOS.  Help would be appreciated in solving this.  :D

Comment: What element are you trying to get from your HTML?

Comment: border=0 title="Women Who Run With The Wolves:  Myths And Stories Of The Wild Woman Archetype"

Comment: Can you add an extract of your HTML that includes the element in which those attributes appear? It's impossible to do XPath without seeing at least some of the document structure. Also, what do you want to retrieve? The contents of the `title` attribute?

Comment: Updated question to show part of the document structure... trying to get the book title... if I can nail this down, then I can get the other attributes for that book hopefully without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this XPath to get `<img>` tag having `title` attribute and having `border` attribute value equals `0`, at any level of HTML document :

```
//img[@title and @border='0']
```

Please clarify if this isn't the element you're trying to get.

**UPDATE :**

Responding to your comment, you can append above XPath with `/@title` to get `title` attribute of the `<img>` ike so :

```
//img[@border='0']/@title
```

Comment: in XPath, `//` means self and descendant of current context node (I guess the context is root element in your case). That's why I said "...at any level of HTML document"

Comment: I think I need to do a lot of reading on XPath... I'm confused... :-{  but I thank you for your time... at least it worked... :D